# CodeIgniter 4 After $mail->send() get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Function to send e-mail in my model

```
    function sendEmail($to,$email_subject,$email_message){
            $email = \Config\Services::email();
            $email->setTo($to);
            $email->setFrom('noreply@coltdrive.pl','ColtDrive');
            $email->setSubject($email_subject);
            $email->setMessage($email_message);
            return $email->send();

    }
```

Controller:

```
public function user_create(){

        if((is_min_role(ROLE_FINANSE))){
            helper(['form']);
            $this->data['page_title']="Towrznie użytkownika";
            $this->data['data']= $this->request;
            $this->data['acc_type'] = 'użytkownika';
            $this->data['rangs'] = $this->db->table('rangs')->select('*')->where("id >= '{$this->session->login_rang}'")->get()->getResultArray();
            $this->data['status'] = $this->db->table('status')->select('*')->get()->getResultArray();
            if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){
                $rules = [
                    'fName' => ['label' => 'Imię', 'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]', 'errors' => ['required' => 'Pole {field} jest wymagane', 'min_length[3]' => 'Pole {field} wymaga conajmniej 3 znaków']],
                    'lName' => ['label' => 'Nazwisko', 'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]', 'errors' => ['required' => 'Pole {field} jest wymagane', 'min_length[3]' => 'Pole {field} wymaga conajmniej 3 znaków']],
                    'email' => ['label' => 'E-mail', 'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]', 'errors' => ['required' => 'Pole {field} jest wymagane',  'valid_email' => '{field} nie spełnia walidacji', 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już wykorzystywany']],
                    'phone' => ['label' => 'Telefon', 'rules' => 'required|regex_match[[\+]?[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{3,5}]|is_unique[users.phone]', 'errors' => ['required' => 'Pole {field} jest wymagane', 'regex_match' => 'Pole {field} wymaga conajmniej 9 cyfr, może posiadać numer kierunkowy z + (nie jest to wymagane)', 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już wykorzystywany']],
                ];
                if($this->request->getVar('acc_number') !== NULL){
                        $add_rule = [
                            'acc_number' => ['label' => 'Numer konta', 'rules' => 'is_unique[users.acc_number]', 'errors' => ['is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już przypisany do innego konta']],
                        ];
                       array_merge($rules,$add_rule);      
                }
                if($this->request->getVar('acc_number_mandate') !== NULL){
                    $add_rule = [
                        'acc_number_mandate' => ['label' => 'Numer konta zleceniówka', 'rules' => 'is_unique[users.acc_number_mandate]', 'errors' => [ 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już przypisany do innego konta']],
                    ];
                    array_merge($rules,$add_rule);
                }
                if($this->request->getVar('apps_1') !== NULL){
                    $add_rule = [
                        'apps_bolt' => ['label' => 'apps_1', 'rules' => 'regex_match[[\+]?[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}?[0-9]{5}]|is_unique[apps.1]', 'errors' => [ 'regex_match' => 'Pole {field} nie spełnia walidacji', 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już przypisany do innego konta' ]],
                    ];
                    array_merge($rules,$add_rule);
                }
                if($this->request->getVar('apps_2') !== NULL){
                    $add_rule = [
                        'apps_uber' => ['label' => 'apps2', 'rules' => 'is_unique[apps.2]', 'errors' => [ 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już przypisany do innego konta']],
                    ];
                    array_merge($rules,$add_rule);
                }
                if($this->request->getVar('apps_3') !== NULL){
                    $add_rule = [
                        'apps_free_now' => ['label' => 'apps3', 'rules' => 'is_unique[apps.3]', 'errors' => [ 'is_unique' => 'Podany {field} jest już przypisany do innego konta']],
                    ];
                    array_merge($rules,$add_rule);
                }
                
                if($this->validate($rules)){
                    $dAppsData = [
                        '1' => $this->request->getVar('apps_1'),
                        '2' => $this->request->getVar('apps_2'),
                        '3' => $this->request->getVar('apps_3'),
                    ];
                    $dAppsSave = $this->apps_model->save($dAppsData);
                    $lastInsertAppsId = $this->apps_model->insertID();
                    if($dAppsSave){
                        $dData = [
                            'fName' => $this->request->getVar('fName'),
                            'lName' => $this->request->getVar('lName'),
                            'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                            'phone' => $this->request->getVar('phone'),
                            'acc_number' => $this->request->getVar('acc_number'),
                            'acc_number_mandate' => $this->request->getVar('acc_number_mandate'),
                            'rang' => $this->request->getVar('rang'),
                            'status' => $this->request->getVar('status'),
                            'apps' => $lastInsertAppsId,
                        ];
                        $dSave = $this->auth_model->save($dData);
                        if($dSave){ 
                            $email = $this->request->getVar('email');
                            $link = '/';
                            $mail_link = base_url($link);
                            $email_subject = 'ColtDrive | Założono dla ciebie konto';
                            $email_message = view('pages/mail/account/user',["fName" => $dData['fName'], "lName" => $dData['lName'], "link" => $mail_link]);
                            if($this->auth_model->sendEmail($email,$email_subject,$email_message)){
                                $this->session->setFlashdata('success','Dane zostały pomyślnie zapisane');
                                return redirect()->to('/');
                            }else{
                                $this->session->setFlashdata('error','Dane dotyczące użytkownika zostały zapisane ale e-mail nie został wysłany');
                                return redirect()->to('/');
                            }

                            
                            
                        }else{
                            $this->session->setFlashdata('error','Tworzenie konta użytkownika zakończone niepowodzeniem');
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('error','Tworzenie konta użytkownika zakończone niepowodzeniem');
                    }
                    
                }else{
                    $this->data['validations'] = $this->validator;  
                    return view('pages/users/create',$this->data);
                }
            }
        }else{
            throw \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException::forPageNotFound();
        }
        return view('pages/users/create',$this->data);
    }
```

Routes:

```
$routes->group('Users', ['filter' => 'auth'], static function($routes){
    $routes->get('lists', 'UsersController::lists');
    $routes->match(['post'], 'driver_create', 'UsersController:driver_create');
    $routes->match(['get','post'], 'user_create', 'UsersController::user_create');
    $routes->get('(:segment)', 'UsersController::$1');
    $routes->get('(:segment)/(:any)', 'UsersController::$1/$2');
    $routes->match(['post'], 'user_edit/(:num)', 'UsersController::user_edit/$1');
});
```

To get into page where i put all data and try to send e-mail is:
Users/user_create and this work on this route:

```
$routes->get('(:segment)/(:any)', 'UsersController::$1/$2');
```

saving data is on:

```
$routes->match(['get','post'], 'user_create', 'UsersController::user_create');
```

Mail send but after this i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I've tried everything and I come to you because I'm out of ideas

[err_empty_respone and url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS97e.png)

I try to send mail but get error (mail is being sent)

ci version : 4.3.1
php: 7.4